# Broadcasting in RUDP, UDT, LWIP, DCCP

Tags: tcp, udp, protocols, broadcast, rudp

Out of the protocols Reliable UDP (RUDP), UDT, LWIP and DCCP, which protocols can support BROADCAST mechanism? Which is more reliable and have congestion control?

Comment: This question seems to be outside the scope of SO - see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions - try http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @TonnyMadsen, network protocol questions are part of computer science and [so] officially welcomes these questions
http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80058/160519

Comment: @MikePennington I stand corrected - we even have a tag for this :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*Reliable UDP*" is a generic moniker that many different implementations relate.  For example, [Plan 9's RUDP](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sources/plan9/sys/src/9/ip/rudp.c) is a simple reliable point-to-point datagram protocol with rudimentary flow control.

"*UDT*" is another point-to-point protocol but targeting high-latency high-bandwidth environments where current TCP congestion logic fails such as intercontinental file transfers.  The protocol implements reliable delivery at the expense of congestion, packets are pushed through on-mass to reduce the overhead of round-trip ACK and NAK mechanisms.

"*LWIP*" I assume refers to the [lightweight IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LwIP) stack and is independent of this discussion.

"*DCCP*" is a means of using [ECN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_Congestion_Notification) to add congestion control above basic datagrams and is orthogonal to reliability.

**So what are available options?**

The most practical would be an [overlay network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlay_network) such as XMPP such that you gain broadcast semantics but leverage TCP congestion controlled connections and HTTP for widespread connectivity.  The cost is complexity in code.

If you really must, [PGM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatic_General_Multicast) is a protocol that can provide reliable delivery with congestion control tuned for wired and wireless networks.  However it depends upon IP multicast which means expensive network infrastructure support and significantly more complicated integration testing.  All present research congestion control mechanisms for PGM saturate and become useless above 10,000 packets-per-second so one has to consider lower packet rates with larger payloads.